# Can I change the position of my app in the default iOS share sheet?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've tried to associate my app with a custom file extension, and it's showing up in the share sheet when the user tries to share that file with my app from another app.

But the problem is that my app is showing up as 6th or 7th app in the share sheet.
The extension is a custom file extension defined by my app. How can I make my app show up as the first app in the share sheet for this specific file extension?

This is how I made my app associate with that file extension.

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>custom file</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>my.package.name.customextension</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.archive</string>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>custom File</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>my.package.name.customextension</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>customextension</string>
            </array>
            <key>public.mime-type</key>
            <string>application/customextension</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: I think, if there is such method, then everybody would use it. How iOS would decide which app should be placed at the top of the list?

Comment: Well, you define a file extension that's not defined anywhere else, so iOS should know that your app is the only one defining that specific file extension :/